# SSH Connection to Ubuntu Server fails with Connection closed <ip> [preauth]

Tags: server, 16.04, openssh

Newly installed Ubuntu Server 16.04, have done the update and upgrades.
Running `sudo service ssh status` says it is up and running. I marked OpenSSH-server during the installation.

But I cannot connect to the machine from my OS X computer.

When I try to connect this happens:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.90 [192.168.1.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mattias/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 
Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.90:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

And then it stops doing anything. Just hangs there.
In the auth.log on the server not much is happening.
After a while it says `Connection closed <ip> [preauth]`.

What can this be? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any error in the log output you provided. Is there any more output after this? It's successfully reading `/Users/mattias/.ssh/id_rsa` and trying to authenticate itself with the username `admin`. Have you created an `admin` user on the server?

Comment: I have no admin user on the server it is called ladmin.

Comment: I got fed up and tried to reinstall openssh-server now when I get the status of it it says it is masked. And not started. And when I try to start it it says no because it is masked.

Comment: Masked? Can you edit your question and add the exact error message?